# Build graph of organizational structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph

I'm having trouble writing an algo that can read a CSV of employee/managers, and output a directed graph featuring the employee/manager relationships.

My foobar example: given the following CSV file

```
john,
jill, john
tom, john
tim, jill
felisa, tom
ray, tom
bob, tim
jim, tim
pam, felisa
ben, ray
james, ray
mike, pam
rashad, ben
henry, james
```

How can I build a DiGraph such that the following organizational structure can be shown:

```
         john
        /    \
     jill    tom
     /       /  \
   tim   felisa  ray
 /  \      /     /  \
bob jim   pam  ben  james
          /     /       \
        mike   rashad    henry
```

Obviously this is a graph problem, but I'm having trouble deciding which structure(s) to use (e.g., would it be best to use a `dict` or to build a custom `OrganizationalGraph` object, etc). Any help is appreciated.

The language of choice isn't really important (though we can just say Python for simplicity [updated tags accordingly]), I'm more so just trying to understand the fundamentals of this type of problem (i.e., recursion vs. iteration, using `set()` to store a manager's direct reports vs using *only* abstracted data structures). **Finally, no, using any package outside of the standard library is a non-starter.**

Comment: Just find a mature graph library for your language, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: For Python you can use networkX.

Comment: Try to create a graph with adjacency list, there are a lot materials on internet. It's fun to implement a Graph by hand, though in practice you would almost always prefer to use a library for performance & correctness & maintainability.

Comment: For Python specifically: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To build the graph we are given the following information:

1. The root (in this case John)
2. A list of edges in the form (child, parent)
3. Each node has a maximum of two children (implied from your example, however the code below works for any node having an arbitrary amount of children)

Note that in your question's example `csv` data you seem to have mispelled `felisa` as `felia`. As a result these outputs aren't for the actual data you put up but rather the corrected version.
First we parse the `csv` file, extracting the root and a list of edges:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as f:
    f = list(csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True))
    root, *edges = f
    root = root[0]

print(root)
print(edges)
```

Output:

```
john 
[['jill', 'john'], ['tom', 'john'], ['tim', 'jill'], ['felisa', 'tom'], ['ray', 'tom'], ['bob', 'tim'], ['jim', 'tim'], ['pam', 'felisa'], ['ben', 'ray'], ['james', 'ray'], ['mike', 'pam'], ['rashad', 'ben'], ['henry', 'james']]
```

We use a `defaultdict` from `collections` (standard library) to represent a graph. We use the `key` in the dictionary to represent the parent / manager, and the `value` to represent a list of children / employees:

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = defaultdict(list)
for child, parent in edges:
    graph[parent].append(child)

print(graph)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'john': ['jill', 'tom'], 'jill': ['tim'], 'tom': ['felisa', 'ray'], 'tim': ['bob', 'jim'], 'felisa': ['pam'], 'ray': ['ben', 'james'], 'pam': ['mike'], 'ben': ['rashad'], 'james': ['henry']})
```

This structure lets us get a list of children of a node with `graph[node]`. We know that the root of the tree is the node that isn't present in any of the values in any of the lists. We also saved the root earlier.

I took "how can I build a DiGraph such that the following organizational structure can be shown" quite literally. Here's an example of how we can traverse this graph structure to build a string representation:

```
res = ''
stack = [(root, 0)]
needed_lines = defaultdict(int)

while stack:
    node, level = stack.pop()
    prev_level = level-4
    res += '\n' + ''.join('|' if i in needed_lines else
                          ' ' if i <= level-4 else
                          '-' for i in range(level)) + node
    for child in graph[node]:
        stack.append((child, level+4))

    needed_lines[level] += len(graph[node])
    needed_lines[prev_level] -=1
    if needed_lines[prev_level] == 0: del needed_lines[prev_level]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
john
|---tom
|   |---ray
|   |   |---james
|   |   |   |---henry
|   |   |---ben
|   |       |---rashad
|   |---felisa
|       |---pam
|           |---mike
|---jill
    |---tim
        |---jim
        |---bob
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are trying to build a *tree graph*. If you do not know how many direct children a node can have, then the most common representation of a tree is as a collection of *node* objects. (If you know an upper limit on the number of children per node and most nodes have that many children, then you can represent the tree efficiently in a simple array.)

Each node has 1 parent and a set of children, which is represented by some kind of data container (usually an Object of class Node in an object-oriented language) that contains references or pointers to the parent and children. Typically this is a single variable for the parent reference and an array for the child references. The one node that has no parent is called the *root* and is stored in a special variable that is used to refer to the whole tree.

You want to arrange the tree so that it is easy to find a node given a name. Going over the various options for that can be a whole Computer Science course so I won't get into it here. You might, in fact, end up storing pointers to nodes in a second, sorted data structure to facilitate finding them quickly.

Then for each input, you find the referenced parent node and add the stated child to it.  For example, when processing `jill, john` you

- Create a new node named `jill`
- Find the node named `john`
- Add `jill` to `john`'s child list
- Set `jill`'s parent to `john`

Does that answer your question?